# WordPress, HTML \\ How to insert <meta> tag in the <head> area of a specific page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, meta, elementor

I want to add a meta tag for my site description inside the head area of a specific page, **before** the body tag opens. The site is built with WordPress & Elementor.

I **don't** want to add it globally like in the theme>>header option here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-inset-code-the-closing-tag/

**I'm looking for another solution besides editing the header.php file** in a way that applies for all the theme pages. If I can do so in this file, and control which pages/posts the added meta tag will apply to, so that will be good.

What is my solution?

**EDIT:** This can be the relevant code at **functions.php**

```
function envo_shop_setup() {

// Theme lang.
load_theme_textdomain('envo-shop', get_template_directory() . '/languages');

// Add Title Tag Support.
add_theme_support('title-tag');

// Register Menus.
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'main_menu' => esc_html__('Main Menu', 'envo-shop'),
        'main_menu_right' => esc_html__('Main Menu Right', 'envo-shop'),
        'main_menu_cats' => esc_html__('Categories Menu', 'envo-shop'),
    )
);

// some templete conditions...

endif;

function envo_shop_pingback_header() {
    if (is_singular() && pings_open()) {
        printf('<link rel="pingback" href="%s">' . "\n", esc_url(get_bloginfo('pingback_url')));
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'envo_shop_pingback_header');
```

Comment: you can use yoast seo plugin to add meta tags in pages

Comment: include a "custom-meta.php" file inside your header.php, and add logic inside that file to write html only in certain cases, bad practice, dirty, but will work

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus Where should I add this kind of a file? As a new file inside the same folder of header.php, as part of the header.php file or other?

Comment: @YairShachar well... both. In order to include a file inside the code, it need to exist, so yes, you create it, write it, insert it the folder and inside the header.php code, this way when your tries to read header.php file it will also read the custom one

Answer (score 2):

If the theme you are using is nothing really weird and special you should have a call like this:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

before the  tag. If that's the case you can use:

```
add_action( 'wp_head',function (){
    // you can pass Page ID, title, slug, or array of such to check against. Default empty.
    if(is_page("mypage")){
        
    }
} );
```

This would put what you need only where you want them to appear using the conditionals tags (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: This a saw in a previous question here,but isn't it global? I think maybe to use the Yoast plugin where I can change the google description, though it is not perfect for adding keywords for search.

Comment: The wp_head hook is indeed global, what makes it restricted to just some page is the conditional tag "is_page" which can hit just the pages you need

Comment: OK I see. So if I got it right, I should to go to header.php, add this code + pagename and inside the script write: 
`code` {    <meta name="description" content="my SEO stuff">    }

Comment: You can add that snippet of code directly inside your functions.php file. And yes, inside the "if(is_page)" you can add that <meta .... > that you need. That should work :)

Comment: Also, can the coe **(is_page("mypage")){}** refate to a post, or should I write is_post?

Comment: Nope, you need to use is_single if you want to check for a post (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/)

Comment: I'm using a templete so it looks like this: add_action('wp_head', 'envo_shop_pingback_header');          Now if I add the function (and close & re-open the php tag) it fails, and makes a "critical" error, that blocks the site for browsers. how to still use this function?

Comment: @YairShachar post the full code in your question please, i can't really understand like this

Comment: Look at my edit at the bottom - it can be fixed, but I tryed to change there and it made a crutuale error for all my site, so I deleted it. Anything possible?

Comment: Your function "envo_shop_pingback_header " should work. What critical error does that function gives you?

Comment: Just says I got a critical error with no explanation or an error number. What can I assume it is?

Comment: You should enable wp_debug in wp-config.php and see what happened